# How to reference the type of superclass field in subclass field

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Ok, so I have noticed that Webstorm and VSCode only do good intellisense for top-level properties, not inheritied properties, etc. So as a trick, I'd like to add properties to super classes that are inherited properties, but just reference the types from the superclass.

Here is a screenshot showing that the two top level properties are in bold, and the inherited properties are in gray:

[image]

I want to trick the IDE, to show some of the inherited properties in bold too. Got it?

I have the following interfaces, one extends the other:

```
export interface IHookOrTestCaseParam {
  slow: () => void,
  fatal: (err: any) => void,
  callbackMode: boolean,
  timeout: Function,
  done: Function,
  skip: () => void,
  set: (k: string, v: any) => void,
  get: (k?: string) => any,
  getValues: (...args: Array<string>) => Array<any>;
  getMap: (...args: Array<string>) => Object
  wrap: (fn: Function) => Function
  wrapFinal: (fn: Function) => Function;
  final: (fn: Function) => void;
  log: (...args: Array<string>) => void;
  wrapFinalErrorFirst: (fn: Function) => Function;
  wrapErrorFirst: (fn: Function) => Function;
  handleAssertions: (fn: Function) => void;
  assert: typeof chai.assert
  expect: typeof chai.expect
  should: typeof chai.should
}


export interface ITestCaseParam extends IHookOrTestCaseParam {
  // the t in t => {}
  (err?: Error): void
  skip:  IHookOrTestCaseParam.skip,  // <<<< here is a problem
  pass: Function,
  fail: Function,
  assert: typeof chai.assert,
}
```

I see this in my IDE:

[image]

if I change this:

```
skip:  IHookOrTestCaseParam.skip,
```

to this

```
skip:  IHookOrTestCaseParam['skip'],
```

The error message seems to go away:

[image]

Does anyone understand what I am trying to do, and know a good way to do it?

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, that isn't a type.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Properties are automatically inherited; you shouldn't need to do anything.

Comment: **Properties are automatically inherited, but intellisense does not work well with inherited properties, so I want to re-reference them.**

Comment: But I want to re-reference them without repeating the type information. The type information is only declared in the superclass.

Comment: You don't fix a glich in your IDE by perverting the code. You use a better IDE, or submit an issue to the IDE vendor. My guess, however, is that the IDE is just fine, but there is a roblem in your code. Why not tell us the actual problem you have with Webstorm?

Comment: The only problem I really trying to solve is to get better intellisense results.

Comment: It makes sense that the IDE would show the top-level properties first, and sometimes only showing the top-level properties. I can trick the IDE into showing inherited properties too.

Comment: It's for a library, so I cannot expect all my users to tweak their IDEs.

Comment: I want to do my users a favor.

Comment: You still haven't explained what the actual problem is, with a concrete example allowing us to reproduce it.

Comment: The problem is that VSCode/Webstorm do not always give you autocomplete options for inherited properties, at least in my experience.

Comment: Let me create an example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I added a new screenshot at the top of the question

Comment: So, everything is fine, but you just disagree with the choice of WebStorm to highlight the properties specific to the subtype. Again, that's really not worth to pollute your code. And actually, you might make the users who agree with WebStorm's design choice unhappy by doing that. Just don't. Or, if you really care about that, again, submit an issue to JetBrains

Comment: I agree with you, but if there is a way to dynamically reference a type from a superclass, it would be a perfectly legal way to trick the IDE. The users don't need to know about the inheritance hierarchy, they just need to know what properties are available.

Comment: OMG, do not, please, do not make your code use inheritance to "fix" the IDE deficiency because the users will not see it... The _coders_ will see that, and they will be confused. Maintenance will become burdensome. Taking it away may not be an easy thing in the future... This is a really really bad idea as others already explained.

Comment: hmmm, not sure what to do, but I hear your points, it might not work very well, I agree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a TypeScript interface can reference the type of another interface's field by name:

```
interface A {
    name: string;
}

interface B {
    name: A['name'];
}
```

Comment: this answers the question, regardless of whether it's a good idea, so I award you the points

Comment: this answers the brilliant question which deserver un upvote lol