# Create private/protected members of interface

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I am looking at the TS docs for interfaces:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

it doesn't look like this is possible:

```
export interface Foo {
 private a: boolean
 protected b: boolean
}
```

the reason I want to use private/protected is so that these fields don't show up in intellisense/autocomplete.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: You can use inheritance to share private properties, but perhaps you shouldn't base your software architecture on what shows up in intellisense?

Comment: @Kokodoko Seems to be a common theme in OP's questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47933320/how-to-reference-the-type-of-superclass-field-in-subclass-field

Answer (score 5):

Interface is public contract, so can't contain non-public at all. For `protected`, abstract class will be way to go but there's no way to enforce private field / method to implementation of interfaces or inherited classes.

Comment: Private and protected members are usually support an implementation detail, and if you need to access them elsewhere, maybe it should be a design decision to expose them through a public access modifier.

Comment: 100% agreed with @DanielPark .

Comment: Exactly. If the field is nonpublic, it shouldn't be possible to enforce it via an interface, which, in turn, would break the concept of the interface.

Comment: Except in JS it's possible to assign a function to a method. In which case it's legit to access this.protectedProp... Unfortunately people are too used to Java limitations and continue to apply the same narrow view in JS.